# Ajax called method not firing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view:

```
@using confidenitial.DB.DataLayer;

<div id="page">
    @{
        List<Network> networks = (List<Network>)ViewData["Networks"];
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">ID</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">Name</td>
                <td style="text-align: center" colspan="2">Modify</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (Network n in networks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        @n.ID
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        @n.Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button>Rename</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="removeNetwork()">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function removeNetwork() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/removeNetwork",
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: id}
            }).done(function (result) {
                $('#page').html(result);
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult removeNetwork(int id)
{
     //query
     return PartialView("_Whatever");
}
```

I want it to call the `removeNetwork` method form the controller but for some reason it's not firing. I would say it's my fault but I wrote the exact same ajax when calling `addNetwork` and that works fine.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function addNetwork() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/addNetwork",
                type: "GET",
                data: { newNetwork: newNetwork.value }
            }).done(function (result) {
                $('#table').html(result);
                $('#newNetwork').val("");
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

What is the big difference between the two? I can't figure it out.

**Edit:**

I found what the problem was: the function can't be in the partial view so I placed it in the main view. I discovered this after looking at the html the server spit out (the script section did not contain this script).

Comment: What are `newNetwork`, `id` and post controller actions

Comment: where newNetwork.value come from in data in ajax call???

Comment: Post the controller and action plz

Comment: `newNetwork` is in the parent view (I posted the partial only)

Answer (score 2):

Your `removeButton` method is reading value of a variable `id` which is neither declared as global or not passed to the method. So change your method to accept that as a parameter.

```
<script>
    function removeNetwork(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/removeNetwork",
            type: "GET",
            data: { id: id }
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#page').html(result);
        });
    }
</script>
```

and in your markup, pass that to your method.

```
<td>
    <button onclick="removeNetwork(@n.ID)">Delete</button>
</td>
```

This should work.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu It should work fine. Here is a working sample. https://dotnetfiddle.net/jGc4rK

Answer (score 0):

You do a GET request in ajax (type: "GET") but your action is configured to be used as POST request ([HttpPost] attribute) you must change the attribute of your action by [HttpGet] or the ajax request by  POST instead of GET